# String input escaping

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm having a problem taking input from a textbox and adding it to a sting, it involves the '\' char. Since a normal string will see this as an escape it will screw up a string that I then pass to another function. I'm new to javascript and yui so I'm just wondering if there is a built in way to escape a string value I get from the textbox, so it will take a '\' and make it a "\" and so on.

My code looks a little like this

```
var requestStr = "\" Request\"";
requestStr = requestStr + "\"" + document.getElementById("textbox").value + "\",";
```

Edit: Fixed code to properly show my example

Comment: Are you saying you want to include the `\\` character in the string?

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript/3561711#3561711).

Comment: @David How can you be 'David' when I'm David?

Comment: @David I am David, therefore I am.

Comment: @David[0] only it they input it in the textbox

Comment: @David[1] That might be the simplest way

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? http://jsfiddle.net/LtAex/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var s=document.getElementById("textbox").value
if(var x=s.IndexOf('\\')){
s[x]='\\';
requestStr =requestStr +s ;
}
else
{
   requestStr =requestStr+ s;
}
```

output will be: "request" "value\" or "request" "value"